# Redirect as a fresh request after using Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an aspx page in VS 2005. I have code like this,

```
int RepID = 0;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
    if(!Page.Ispostback)
    {
        get value from database and display it in textbox;
    }
    else 
    {

    }
}
protected void Save_OnClick(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
    Update Database with modified textbox Text ;
    Response.Redirect(//To the same page);
}
```

After the Response.Redirect, i was looking for the page to refresh and get the modified value from database. Instead, it uses the else loop in Page_load and displays the old value because it doesn't go into the if loop as it is the Postback. How can i display from database after the response.redirect is used. I know i am missing a logic but i am not sure what? Thanks alott guys..

Comment: A `Response.Redirect` is never seen as a postback. Have you set a breakpoint to see what's actually happening?

Comment: My faultttttt, I am sorry!! Thanks James

Comment: Additionally is there need for response.redirect if your are posting back on the same page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete

```
Response.Redirect(//to same page);
```

Your Save button click should post back to the same page it is on.